# Setting the Properties included in the app.manifest at compile time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, manifest

I have the following manifest in one project of mine (created on Visual Studio 2013, on C#).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="5.4.0.5" name="Device"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"><security><requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3"><requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" /></requestedPrivileges></security></trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"><application></application></compatibility>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

The "assemblyIdentity" tag contains the project name and version; is there a way to mark this properties with a code to get both values from the project at compiler time, instead of changing it on the file?

Comment: How about using post-build event?

Comment: The assemblyIdentity element must be present to make it a valid manifest, the OS demands it.  It however plays no role whatsoever in a C# project, it only matters in native apps that use winsxs.  Managed code always uses the GAC.  So they did not automate it nor make it easy to change at build time, there was no need to provide the feature.  Get ahead by simply not changing it.

Comment: thank you, i'll leave if a fixed version number then - i don't know how would do it using pre/pos build event "Reniuz"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this with something i found and solved my need, at [MSDN's page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2015) they show how to Specify Build Events (C#) and use as an example a Build Event to change App Manifest.